# Determine the on resistance of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am using IXFK300N20X3 MOSFET for PWM low side switch to heat a piece of metal. The pulse train was 10V(200mA), 100Hz and 0.7% duty cycle. The power supply was in Controlled voltage mode and set at 170V.

The circuit was on a large heat sink and 2 fans were used. The temperatures of the circuit components were measured using thermal-couples and they were below 50% of the max rating.

In **constant DC** heating scheme, the resistance of the metal changed from 400 mOhms to 6.5 Ohms when applying 9A.

In DC pulsing scheme, at 170V applied voltage, I measured the voltage drop across the load to be 100V using an oscilloscope in math mode. The metal piece was at a constant temperature and at the same temperature (2500K) in constant DC heating, the resistance was 6 Ohms. With that info, I calculated the current to be 100V/6 Ohms = 17A which is reasonable.

However, I assumed the other 70V dropped across the transistor and 4mOhms on resistance, the current = 70V/4mOhms = 17.5kA! Unfortunately, I don't have access to the experiment for another few weeks so I can't make the exact measurements.

Is it correct to assume the 70V drop was entirely across the MOSFET?

Best!

[image: This is more or less what my setup looked like.]

Comment: Well, we can rule out 17.5 kA. That was not happening! One possibility is that your measurements are incorrect somehow. It would be better to use a differential high voltage probe to measure the voltage across the transistor directly while it is on, and also a current probe so you can measure the true (as opposed to assumed) current and voltage at the same time. One possibility is that Rds is much higher than 4 mOhms. If you assume that the current of 17 A is correct, then the implied resistance is 70/17 = 4.1 Ohms.

Comment: Another possibility is that voltage is being dropped in wires leading to the MOSFET or from the MOSFET to the load.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for your suggestions. We are debating on buying a current probe. They are very pricy! Also, my labmate was able to measure the voltage across the MOSFET and it was 50V (math mode). However, the minimum voltage of the high side (load's low side) was negative. This makes me think that floating the leads might not give accurate readings or something peculiar happened.